# GCD and LCM; linear system

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What would be the idea to solve this challenge down?
What I found in a book of theory of numbers, and principui found easily, and now I realize I can not solve.

> Solve the equation system, namely, find value(s) of unknown factor(s) in the following system:
>   $$\begin{align}
> \mathrm{gcd}(x, y) &= 6\\
> \mathrm{lcm}(x, y) &= 60\end{align}$$
>   $$$$
>   $$(x,y)=6\Longrightarrow6\mid x\;\;\text{and}\;\;6\mid y$$

Comment: What does "mcm" mean here? Is it the same as "least common multiple"?

Comment: @CameronWilliams  That's right, I had written wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $gcd(x, y) lcm(x, y) = xy$,
$xy = 360$.

Since
$gcd(x, y) = 6$,
$x = 6a$ and $y = 6b$
for some $a$ and $b$,
so
$36ab = 360$
or $ab = 10$.

The possible values for $(a, b)$
are
(with $a \le b$)
$(1, 10)$ and $(2, 5)$.
This gives
$(x, y) 
= (6, 60)
$
or
$(12, 30)$,
and both of these have
$gcd(x, y) = 6$ and
$lcm(x, y) = 60$.

Comment: Understood, cool, and incredible. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

We can set $x=6a,y=6b$ where $(a,b)=1$

So, mcm$(x,y)=6ab=60$

$\implies ab=10$ with $(a,b)=1$

So, $(a,b)$ can be $(1,10),(2,5),(5,2),(10,1)$

Comment: I did not, because setting $x=6a$ and $y=6b$?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, please pinpoint your doubt/query.

Comment: Why set $$x=6a$$and$$y=6b$$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior We know that both of them are divisible by $6$ since their least common multiple is $6$.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, as gcd$(x,y)=6$ we can set so.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Got everything now, cool. Very very very good.