# Solving $a^2+b^2=2020, \text{lcm}(a,b)=336$ for $a$ and $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What are the  ordered pairs  $(a,b)\in \Bbb{N}\times \Bbb{N}$  satisfying  the following: 
$$a^2+b^2=2020.$$
$$\text{lcm}(a,b)=336.$$

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2020=4\cdot505$ and $336=16\cdot21$.  Since both $2020=a^2+b^2$ and $336=\rm{lcm}(a,b)$ are even, $a$ and $b$ must both be even.  Writing $a=2\alpha$ and $b=2\beta$, so that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=505$, we see that one of $\alpha,\beta$ is even and the other is odd.  Let's assume $\alpha$ is even and $\beta$ is odd.  Then we must have $a=2\alpha=16\alpha'$ with $\alpha'$ odd, in order for $16$ be the largest power of $2$ to divide $\rm{lcm}(a,b)=\rm{lcm}(2\alpha,2\beta)$ with odd $\beta$.  But since $48^2=2304\gt2020$, we can only have $\alpha'=1$.  Hence $a=16$, which implies $b=\sqrt{2020-256}=42=2\cdot21$.  Thus the only solutions in positive integers are $(a,b)=(16,42)$ and $(a,b)=(42,16)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Clearly $a,b$ must be even(why?)

$(a,b)$ must divide $(2020,336)=4$

Check for the positive integer solutions for the two cases

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more please?  i have exam tomorrow

Comment: @prayersmith, Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470807/prove-that-gcdm-n-times-mboxlcmm-n-m-times-n

Comment: @prayersmith, See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328510/simple-question-pertaining-to-lcm,   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456119/gcd-and-lcm-linear-system  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486444/finding-the-number-of-pairs-with-given-gcd-and-lcm-proof

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b) = n$, $a = pn$ and $b = qn$. Then
$$
a^2 + b^2 = (p^2 + q^2)n^2 = 2020.
$$
Thus $n^2$ divides $2020$, but as $2020 = 2^2\cdot5\cdot 101$ contain only one square in its prime decomposition there are only two options: $(a,b) = 1$ and $(a,b) = 2$. Then using the fact that $ab = (a,b)[a,b]$ we may easily check both these two options.

If $(a,b) = 1$ then $ab = 336$ and we get $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab = 2692$ which is not perfect square.

Thus $(a,b) = 2$, then $ab = 2\cdot 336 = 672$, and we get 
$$
(a+b)^2 = 2020 + 2\cdot672 = 58^2 \\
(a-b)^2 = 2020 - 2\cdot672 = 26^2
$$
which gives two solutions $a = 42$, $b=16$ or vice cersa.

Comment: Why not a=6; b=112; or  a=2;b=336; or  a=14;b=48?

Comment: @fleablood well, I think that because theese pairs are not solutions of system $a^2 + b^2 = 2020$, $ab = 672$

Answer (score 0):

LCM is $336 = 2^4*3*7$.  So one is divisible by 3 and the other may or may not be.  One is divisible by 7 and the other may or may not be.  One is divisible by 16 and the other, if divisible by 2, is divisible up to but not more than $2^4$

If $d = \gcd(a,b)$ then $d^2|a^2 + b^2 = 4^2*5*101$-- which is divisible by $2^2$ but no higher power, and not divisible by $3$ or $7$.  So that means $7$ divides one but not the other, $3$ divides one and not the other, and although $16$ divides one the greatest power of $2$ that divides the other is $2$.  Furthermore, we know $2$ divides the other. (If $p|a$ and $p|a^2 + b^2$ then $p|b^2 = (a^2 +b^2) - a^2$)

So we know (wolog) $a = 2a'$ and $b = 16b'$ (or vice versa), $a',b'$ odd. and $a'^2 + 64b'^2 = 505$.

If $7|b'$ we have $64b'^2 \ge 64*49 > 505$ so $7|a'$.  Also if $3|b'$ we have $64b'^2 \ge 64*9 > 505$. So $3,7|a'$ and we have:

$a'=21a"$ and $441a"^2 + 64b'^2 =505$.

Okay, doesn't take much to figure out that $a" =1; b'=1$ is the only solution.  So $a = 42$ and $b=16$ (or vice versa) and $a^2 + b^2 = 1764 + 256 = 2020$.

So the ordered pairs are $(42,16)$ and $(16,42)$.